# Talend Open Studio POST request: "Missing form parameter: grant_type"

Tags: json, rest, post, oauth-2.0, talend

I am using Talend Open Studio to call the Commerzbank API with a POST request to get a refresh token.
I get the error message "Missing form parameter: grant_type", which confuses me, as my tREST component looks like this:
[image]

In Postman everything worked well using this config:
[image]

Do I maybe need to place Content type  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" in a different way/place?

Thank you in advance for any hint :)

Answer (score 0):

I was confusing things here: x-www-form-urlencoded does not ask for a json body, but something in the format like param1=value1&param2=value2

Answer (score 0):

You can view code in the right level at Postman an get the java code from there .

[https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#:~:text=In%20Postman%2C%20select%20the%20request,copy%20your%20generated%20code%20snippet](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/generate-code-snippets/#:%7E:text=In%20Postman%2C%20select%20the%20request,copy%20your%20generated%20code%20snippet).

Then you  can paste the wanted code in a tjava .
The last step is to call it in query or body in tREST .